Continuity with respect to Wasserstein metric.
I am trying to find some literature related to the following problem:
Let $P,Q$ be Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the family of all intervals. Let also $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded Lipschitz function. I am looking at the quantity
$$\sup_{I\in \mathcal{I}}\left|\frac{1}{P(I)}\int_I f\, dP-\frac{1}{Q(I)}\int_I f\, dQ\right|.$$
Is this continuous with respect to some integral probability metric (say, the Wasserstein metric)?
Is it at least continuous if we restrict $\mathcal{I}$ to the intervals whose $P,Q$-measures are lower bounded by a constant?
It looks like an integral probability metric itself, but it also contains the normalizing factors that I find hard to deal with. Is there any related literature? Thank you in advance!
